# If I remove a dependency from Gradle does it get uninstalled?

Tags: android, gradle

I included an open source library in my Gradle dependency list and no longer wish to use it. If I remove the line from the Gradle compile path, does the project get removed from my app or do I have to somehow go delete it manually somewhere?

Comment: The lib is not longer available for your project. Nothing to worry. Move on.. Probably read about dependencies and gradle @ https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a compiled library under the dependencies list, Android Studio will ask you to **SYNC NOW**, in order to *clean* and *rebuild* the project. It will indeed be removed. *(You can compare the apk size before/after, you will see)*

```
dependencies {
    //compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you delete the dependency from the gradle compile path and then clean and rebuild project, android studio automatically purges the dependency from the android application. 
However,If if you have included the library manually in **apps/libs** folder you will need to manually delete the module from the disk which although will not be present in the application apk but will still be in the project.If you might need it for further use , you can keep it in the disk.